# Escaping characters in cookies

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, python-2.7, escaping

This is my code:

```
import webapp2
class Index(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get_cookie(self, name, notfound=""):
        return self.request.cookies.get(name, notfound)
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', "Foo=Hello World!")
        self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', "Bar=With, Commas")

        txt1 = self.get_cookie("Foo", "Foo cookie not found!")
        txt2 = self.get_cookie("Bar", "Bar cookie not found!")

        self.response.out.write(txt1 + " " + txt2)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Index)], debug=True)
```

The code will output, but it has trouble outputting...

[image]

The browser doesn't even escape spaces... What should I do to display the cookie values correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the response [`.set_cookie()` method](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#guide-response-setting-cookies) instead:

```
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'

    self.response.set_cookie('Foo', 'Hello World!)
    self.response.set_cookie('Foo', 'With, Commas')
```

which takes care of proper escaping, etc.